# bx slider with custom pager having issues moving between slides on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

So, I'm using the [bx slider plugin](https://bxslider.com/) for a custom slideshow. I made a custom pager because the requirements are for the slideshow to be in the center of several blocks of content which will act as the pager, and I need to have the items on different sides of the slideshow. The slideshow will auto rotate until a user hover's over a content block, which will move to and freeze the slide on the one related to that item.

Prototype:
https://codepen.io/Denzy/pen/OqBXxq

I **almost** have it working. In my example above, it works briefly but if I move my mouse quickly between items the whole thing freezes up. If I change the pager's **'on'** event to be **'click'** everything works as intended, but I need it to be when you hover over an item, not click. This leads me to believe that the problem has something to do with hovering over a different item before the slider finishes moving from the first item, and things get broken.

My current mouse events look like this:

```
$('#slide-container .pager-list a').on('mouseenter', function() {
    slider.goToSlide(this.getAttribute('data-slide-index'));
    slider.stopAuto();
});

$('#slide-container .pager-list a').on('mouseleave', function() {
    slider.startAuto();
});
```

***Edit:** Rest of the jQuery:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#slide-container',
    slideWidth: 400,
    controls: false,
    auto: true,
    autoHover: true,
    pause: 2000
});

slider.bxSlider();
```

If that is the issue, what can I do to prevent the slide from moving until the first sliding action is complete?

Comment: Need the rest of the jQuery like `bxSlider()` instantiation?

Comment: The rest of the code was in the codepen link, but added it here for better visibility.

Comment: No worries see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269810/2813224).

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Relevant Changes

1. Remove extra instantiation of `.bxSlider()`, you only need one on `ul.bxslider`
2. Remove `pagerCustom` option because it will expect the links to be clicked (which OP request that behavior to be excluded explicitly).
3. Add `pager: false`. We will rely on jQuery event delegation to invoke bxSlider methods.
4. Narrow down the selectors for mouse events:

   ```
      $('.pager').on(MOUSEEVENT, 'a', function() {...
   ```
5. Change `mouseenter` event to `mouseover` event. `mouseenter` only covers when mouse crosses over an element border, while `mouseover` covers the border crossing and the duration in which the pointer is within said element.
6. Change:

   ```
     ...(this.getAttribute('data-slide-index')) // Result is a String ex. "1"<br>
   ```

   to:

   ```
     ...($(this).data('slide-index')) // Result is a Number ex. 1
   ```

### Optional Changes

1. Each link `href` attribute value is set to `#/` which prevents `<a>` *jumping* behavior.
2. Each `<img>` URL parameter for text has been changed to this pattern:

   ```
    &text=Slide%20N
   ```

   `%20` = a space and **N** = a number 1 to 6

---

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    li {
      padding: 20px 0;
    }
    
    .active {
      color: red;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #64758a;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="slide-container">
    <ul class="pager">
      <li> <a data-slide-index="0" href="#/">Slide 1</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a data-slide-index="1" href="#/">Slide 2</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a data-slide-index="2" href="#/">Slide 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide%201" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide%202" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide%203" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide%204" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide%205" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide%206" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pager">
      <li> <a data-slide-index="3" href="#/">Slide 4</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a data-slide-index="4" href="#/">Slide 5</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a data-slide-index="5" href="#/">Slide 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      slideWidth: 400,
      controls: false,
      auto: true, //should be set to true
      autoHover: true,
      pause: 2000,
      pager: false
    });

    $('.pager').on('mouseover', 'a', function() {
      slider.goToSlide($(this).data('slide-index'));
      slider.stopAuto();
    });

    $('.pager').on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
      slider.startAuto();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I was trying to pass a string vs a number... this still plagues me from time to time. Also thank you for suggesting removing "pagerCustom", for some reason I believed I needed that if I was doing any custom pager but that was before I actually started any of the mouse events. Now that I'm looking at everything as a whole, it makes perfect sense as to why it is not needed. I really appreciate the detailed answer, I definitely learned something today!

Comment: I'm glad I can help. Happy coding!